# Magento Error: "Illegal scheme supplied, only alphanumeric characters are permitted"

Tags: error

I have pasted the text shown in error log file from magento/var/report

```
a:5:{i:0;s:67:"Illegal scheme supplied, only alphanumeric characters are permitted";i:1;s:765:"#0 /home/dyamigos/public_html/s/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php(777): Zend_Uri::factory('dyamigos.com/s/...')
#1 /home/dyamigos/public_html/s/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(332): Mage_Core_Model_Store->isCurrentlySecure()
#2 /home/dyamigos/public_html/s/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(161): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->_checkBaseUrl(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#3 /home/dyamigos/public_html/s/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#4 /home/dyamigos/public_html/s/magento/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#5 /home/dyamigos/public_html/s/magento/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#6 {main}";s:3:"url";s:11:"/s/magento/";s:11:"script_name";s:20:"/s/magento/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Please help me out !!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you configured the base URL as `dynamigos.com/` instead of `http://dynamigos.com/`

Since you cannot access the backend now, you have to change it directly in the database. Search the table `core_config_data` for `path='web/secure/base_url'` and `path='web/unsecure/base_url'` and change the values accordingly.